# Can a singleton be made without a private constructor?

Tags: c#, singleton

```
    private static PostalCodeInfoTable postalCodeInfoTable = new PostalCodeInfoTable();

    public static PostalCodeInfoTable GetInstance() { return postalCodeInfoTable; }


    public PostalCodeInfoTable()
    {
        db = new GetConnectionString());
    }
```

I use the GetInstance() to create a PostalCodeInfoTable, then I use a member function to load some data that I haven't shown here, then I use GetInstance again and then data is already pre-loaded, so it seems we have a singleton, but I'm confused theoretically why we can do this with a public constructor

Comment: Hiding the constructor prevents instatiating the class outside of it thus making it a singleton in the first place.

Comment: the constructor here is hidden?

Comment: No, obviously you made it `public`. It would be hidden if you declared it `private`.

Comment: Seems wrong to me. Maybe the person you should be asking is the person who wrote the code. If that person was you, then *why are you asking us why you implemented the pattern wrong*?

Comment: It seems wrong to me too, that's the point of my question

Comment: I tested it, it works just like a singleton, but I don't understand how

Comment: I can't figure out what this question is asking. Someone wrote a class that is not a singleton, you think it was intended to be a singleton, you've correctly deduced that it is wrong, and your question is *what* exactly?

Comment: The defining factor of a singleton/factory pattern is that nobody **but** the factory method can create a instance. That way you can make certain instantiation work that is beyond the Constructor/average code user is done correctly. Or that you always hand out the same instance.

Comment: @DevinAndresSalemi You don't have a singleton, you have a static object you created and can access through a method. You could create another `PostalCodeInfoTable` simply by calling `new PostalCodeInfoTable()`. Perhaps you need to show some more code?

Comment: This code is NOT a singleton, because you can create the instance of that class on purpose in any part of code. Let us assume that you create a library with some class, and write it like this you posted here. Then the person that uses this class can create an instance of it in any part of their code. This is not Singleton pattern

Comment: oh okay so the essence is that only one is possible, otherwise it is simply static?

Comment: I think there is some fundamental disconnect here. Can you say what you believe "singleton" means?

Comment: Did yo perhaps try to learn class semantics by working with Strings? strings are the last class you should ever use for that. It is basically the opposite of normal class behavior in a dozen ways. Between it comparing like a value type (as opposed to all other classes) and string interning it can really mess with your understanding of classes/instances of classes behave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A singleton cannot be made without a private constructor!

If a class has a public constructor, then anybody can create an instance of it at any time, that would make it not a singleton.

In order for it to be a singleton there can only be one instance.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

> An implementation of the singleton pattern must:
>
> 1. ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists;
> 2. and provide global access to that instance.
>
> Typically, this is done by:
>
> 1. declaring all constructors of the class to be private;
> 2. and providing a static method that returns a reference to the instance.

Comment: then how spring always creates singleton object? we are not writing any private constructor in our class right?

Comment: An enum constructor is implicitly private, so you could go Singleton mySingleton = Singleton.Instance;; without explicitly creating a private constructor. You could then go mySingleton.DoSomething() as you would with a non-enum class.

Answer (score 2):

A singleton is nothing more that an instance of a class that is *expected* to have only a single instance. Usually you would hide the constructor by making it private and using a static member to access it, making sure only a single instance can exist within your application.

As the constructor is public, you can still create a new instance. Making it no longer a 'Singleton' by definition, however this does not mean it cannot behave as one.

Answer (score 1):

What you created here is a static variable (PostalCodeInfoTable.postalCodeInfoTable) that can only be accessed through a static method (PostalCodeInfoTable.GetInstance()).

The PostalCodeInfoTable instance is created by the [TypeConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229018.aspx), wich is rarely used outside of runtime constant declaration.

The public constructor? That one is totally irrelevant. I am not sure what purpose it has. It can not affect what is int the static field. Indeed all it does is break the single pattern:

```
var temp1 = PostalCodeInfoTable.GetInstance();
var temp2 = new PostalCodeInfoTable();

//This will return false, as they are not the same instances
object.ReferenceEquals(temp1, temp2);
```

Comment: Please don't use snippet unless you are posting JS/HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of the singleton pattern **must**:

- ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists;
- provide global access to that instance.

Typically, this is done by:

- ***declaring all constructors of the class to be private***;
- providing a static method that returns a reference to the instance.

The instance is usually stored as a private static variable; the instance is created when the variable is initialized, at some point before the static method is first called.

Correct example:

```
public class PostalCodeInfoTable{

    //.........

    private static PostalCodeInfoTable Instance = new PostalCodeInfoTable();

    private PostalCodeInfoTable() {
        db = new GetConnectionString();
    }

    public static PostalCodeInfoTable GetInstance() {
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an enum like so:

```
public enum PostalCodeInfoTable
{
    Instance
}
```

You can then access this instance using:

```
var postalCodeInfoTable = PostalCodeInfoTable.Instance;
```

The Instance value within the enum implicitly represents the single instance of PostalCodeInfoTable. The C# runtime guarantees that enum values are initialized only once, making this a thread-safe way to implement a singleton.

**EDIT**: Can whoever has marked me down please tell me what is wrong with my solution? An enum is a class, and this is a valid way of creating a singleton without an explicit private constructor.